# How to pass a variable using a ionicPopup directive?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to create 3 general ionicPopup templates( Success, Error, warning) and show them in different occasions in my whole app.
But in every occasion it will be a different message. So I need to pass a text variable every time I'm calling the ionicPopup

What I have until now:

```
var successPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                 scope: $scope,
                 title: 'Successful',
                 templateUrl: 'success.html'
                });

<script id="success.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="text-center"><img ng-src="img/icons/successicon.png"></img><br><p>Success Message</p></div> 
</script>
```

How can I use a variable that I will assign in my AngularJS app, and display it in my

tags instead of a static "Success Message"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is to bind a custom object with your message throughout the scope:

```
$scope.message = 'Your custom message';

var successPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    scope: $scope,
    title: 'Successful',
    templateUrl: 'success.html'
});

<script id="success.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="text-center">
        <img ng-src="img/icons/successicon.png"></img>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div> 
</script>
```

I recommend reading this before to understand how works the two-way data binding on AngularJS: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp

Comment: "*Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.*". Explain your code.

Comment: The issue with your solutions is I guess if the script template is in the same js file. In my case, my "scripts" located in the index.html and Im calling them from my .js file. So I dont think the $scope variable will be seen in the index.html.

Comment: Instead of use `templateUrl` attribute, why don't use `template` and declare here your HTML?

Comment: I know how to bind variables. But thats not working with ionicPopup

Comment: @JonathanBrizio because that's the same concept as I have now I guess, each time calling the same template just with different text. And I have a bunch of templates in my index.html. Im trying to avoid repeating the template

Comment: You are right @JonathanBrizio. It was not working cause of a mistake within my code. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks for your time.